# auto fill form and submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a form on my 404 page that is auto filled with the address the user tried to find. I also have javascript that then auto submits that form.

The problem is, once it auto submits it keeps looping and the page keeps reloading.

I am trying to wright the javascript code to fire once and then stop.
The script fires on page load so that's whats causing the loop.

Outcome: I need it to fire on page load, page reloads, the code checks to see if its already reloaded once then stops.

For my test I am trying to make it pop an alert that says "I reloaded once" just so I know its worked.

This is my code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { 
var grabedurl = window.location.href
document.getElementById('badurl').value=grabedurl;
if( history.previous != history.current ){alert('I reloaded once')}
else
setTimeout("document.getElementById('errorsubmit').click()", 3000);}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add the state of the page already having been reloaded or not to the query string part of the URL. This should be done in your `form`'s `action`, e.g. `action="?submitted"`

```
window.onload = function()
{ 
    var form = document.getElementById("aspnetForm");
    form.setAttribute("action", form.getAttribute("action") + "&submitted");
    var grabedurl = window.location.href;
    document.getElementById('badurl').value = grabedurl;
    if (/submitted/.test(window.location.search.substring(1)))
    {
        alert('I reloaded once');
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('errorsubmit').click()", 3000);
    }
}
```

However, you might want to consider alternative approaches -- such as submitting the form via an XMLHttpRequest; having another, separate `action` page to submit the form to, or having the server log the request.

Comment: we are using a content management solution called Ektron. This means I can't alter the forms action or XML Http Request. :(

Comment: You could dynamically alter the form's `action`, but it won't be pretty (but, then again, it will still gracefully degrade since the form will no longer auto-submit). Do you have the `id` or the `class` of the form available?

Comment: <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/Pagenotfound.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/this is a test/" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">

Comment: Does Pagenotfound.aspx have the same form?

Comment: the hole page is incapacitated inside this form. There are maybe 3 submit buttons within this one form. Ektrons somehow tracks which button is clicked and only fires the buttons submit action. - Thus the comment, I cant alter the form tag. The other submit buttons have to be able to fire there functions.

Comment: Right now the alert is poping as soon as page loads

Comment: Ok, quick thing, the reload doesn't go to /Pagenotfound.aspx
it goes to /Pagenotfound.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/XXXXXXX
how do we alter your code to check the reload if XXXXX will always be unknown...split it at the ?

Comment: Oh, then your browser must be redirecting to the `Pagenotfound.aspx` page automatically. Let me post my original solution again.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unknown" there

Comment: this code sits on a 404 error page. The error path will = whatever the user was trying to find...it could be anything, from "this little pony" to "bobstrucks.html"

Comment: Did you try my new code, which adds `&submitted` to the form's action?

Comment: Ok well the original solution poped a bad url request /Pagenotfound.aspx&amp;submitted.
...
The page just says "Bad Request"

Comment: Sorry, I have to leave the office, I will check in on this 2morrow @ 930am EST

Comment: Oh, your CMS must be escaping `&` to `&amp;`. This is getting messier and messier...

Comment: Yes it does get messy sometimes

Comment: I tried changing the ("action") + "&submitted"); to ("action") + "&amp;submitted");
but still got a "Bad Request" url "/error.aspx&amp;submitted"

Comment: This is an answer I got from a friend, it seems to work well.

<script type="text/javascript"> 
            window.onload = function() { 
                var grabedurl = window.location.href 
                document.getElementById('badurl').value=grabedurl;

if( document.referrer != window.location.href ){ 
alert('hello'); 
setTimeout("document.getElementById('errorsubmit').click()", 3000); 
} else {
alert('submitted'); 
}
            } 
</script>